# Android slide left right UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-sliding

[image: Android UI]

I am trying to create a android UI with sliding feature in the middle of the screen. I only have MainAcitivity.java and trying to figure out how this can be done. Is there a control already in the sdk?. I see the sample which does the slide for the entire activity screen but not within the activity. Can you guys provide some ideas on how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ViewPager... It is not necesary to use fragments.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ABOUT THE IMAGE" >
        </Button>

<Button
            android:id="@+id/last"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SOME OTHER TEXT" >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here an example.
http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/

Here an example  using viewpager with fragments :
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/